# Parametric Equations: Find $\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, parametric

> Find $\dfrac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}$, as a function of $t$, for the given the parametric equations: $$\begin{align}x&=3-3\cos(t)\\y&=3+\cos^4(t)\end{align}$$
>   $\displaystyle\dfrac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}=\ldots$

I don't really understand this section that I am learning at all, is there any useful website I can look over to help me understand this concept better?
Thanks!

Comment: From what I skimmed, this gives a pretty simple breakdown of what the question requires. http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mc-ty-parametric-2009-1.pdf

Comment: @Zhoe This is perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Your Welcome @Christopher23

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is known that $$ \dfrac {\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \dfrac {\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}}. $$Do you know how to find $y'(t)$ and $x'(t)$? Do this to get $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ and then differentiate again. I am not finishing the whole thing for you since you haven't shown your work, but I think this hint should help you enough to finish.

Comment: Thanks! Just looking for a brief idea!

Comment: You're welcome! Accept, please? :P

Answer (score 6):

You're given $x(t), y(t)$. So find $\dfrac{dx}{dt},\;\dfrac{dy}{dt}$.

$$\text{Then note that}\;\frac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$$

Now you need to find $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$.

Comment: Beat you! $\mathrm{}\\$ +1, nevertheless.

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another TU +1

Comment: Hi, dear friend, @B.S.! 8)

Comment: @amWhy: Hiiiii. Hope you are doing well. :-) But, I have not been so good today. Many of questions are in especial fields. :(